# How to make table work on click of a button only

Tags: javascript, html

I want the tables values to be updated only by onlick of the button. Currently my form is onload. So the table is generated with null values. But I want onclick of a button that all the values are retreived. And if I click on the button again the table will be updated again. Here is my code so far.

```
 <input type="button" id="button" value="Click to show states" onclick="showState()"/>

    <div id="hidden" style="display:none"> 
        <table id="base" border="10" style="width:300px">
        <tr>
          <td>Type</td>
          <td>URL State</td>
          <td>Server State</td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        <tr>
          <td>Product</td>
          <td><%=product%></td>
          <td><script>getSelectedProduct()</script></td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>

window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = showState;
}

function showState()
{   
    var productServer = document.getElementById("productServer");
    productServer = getSelectedProduct();

    if (document.getElementById("hidden").style.display == "block")
    {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that the table is only being updated on pageload and the button only displays the original table that was made on pageload. I do not want to refresh the page to update my table. I want it to be updated once you click the button

Comment: I have tried making an id in the td of the getSelectedProduct() and putting var product = getProduct() in my showState method becuase it is updating at that point but only in that method. I cannot then get that value into my table

Comment: I think what you trying to accomplish is going to require an AJAX call to go out to the database or a file and return back your updated result set

Comment: what if I just want the table to update onclick of the button. For example have it call all the get methods on the click of the button. How would I do that

Comment: for example, what if statement would I need so that if the button is clicked run table and have it generate values from javascript methods